# After moving from node-sass to dart sass, compiler throws error in keyframes mixin

Tags: css, webpack, sass, node-sass

I'm forced to change sass compiler in my project. I was using node-sass, now I need to change it to dart sass.

I basically done, what it says in [webpack documantation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        // Prefer `dart-sass`
        implementation: require('sass'),
    },
},
```

And when I run compilation it gives me error:

```
 SassError: expected selector.
      ╷
    3 │   0%{
      │   ^
      ╵
```

It is in my animations file. My keyframes mixin:

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {

  -webkit-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }

  -moz-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

And my animation:

```
@include keyframes(bounceDown) {

  0% {
    transform : translateY(0);
  }

  40% {
    transform : translateY(7px);
  }

  100% {
    transform : translateY(0);
  }

}
```

When i was using node-sass this code worked. Any idea what I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out!

Problem was that I used `-moz-keyframes` instead of `@-moz-keyframes`. 
It was handled by node-sass properly.. but it seems that it is error for dart sass.

Cheers!